# unordered_map<int,int>mp({{0, 1}}); what does the thing in bracket mean?

Tags: c++, stl

I saw this in a piece of code!

I just wanted to know the meaning of the thing in bracket. It is not clear to me means syntax not clear.
so, please help me out of it.

Count the occurrence of all prefix sum.

I didn't notice that the array contains only 0 and 1,
so this solution also works if have negatives

Comment: Lets go inside out `{0,1}` creates a std::pair<key_type,value_type>, the next {} means that you will have an initializer list of pairs of key value types. This is then passed to the constructor of the unordered_map. So in the end you will create a map with value 1 at key 1. And you say that you didn't notice the array has values 0 and 1... that's because you have an unordered_map not an array

Comment: [tag:dsa] has nothing to do with the code in the title. Please read the tag description carefully when you pick them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're creating a map and initializing with only one key pair. so the map has only one key pair `{0,1}`:

- The **Key** to accessing this pair is **0**
- The **Value** of this pair is **1**

```cpp
unordered_map<int,int>mp
unordered_map<int,int>mp{ } //this bracket stands for empty map.
unordered_map<int,int>mp { {0,1} } // created map with one 0->1 (key->value)
```